# Parse std::string for a selection of characters

Tags: c++, regex, string

Is there an easy way to parse a `std::string` in search of a list of certain charcters? For example, let's say the user enters `this<\is a.>te!st string`. I'd like to be able to spot those non-letter characters are there and do something about it. I'm looking for a general purpose solution that allows me to simply specify a list of `char`s so I can reuse the function in different situations. I'm guessing regular expressions will play a key role in any solution, and obviously the more compact and effience, the better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`std::string::find_first_not_of()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_not_of/) for this. It'll find the characters except those in the set that you give it. Its counterpart, `find_first_of()`, will search for characters that *are* in the set.

Both functions allow you to specify the starting index. This will enable you you to continue the search from where you left off.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a regex library like [boost::regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html)?
[This](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_replace.html) should exactly do what you are looking for.
If your compiler supports C++11 you can use std::regex.

Answer (score 0):

Regex seems like overkill. You can use `std::string`'s methods: `find_first_of()` and/or `find_last_of()`. [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) you can find documentation and examples.